# Как в VSCode быстро перейти из терминала к редактированию файла mac osx?

Tags: visual-studio

VSCode есть встроенный терминал, есть ли стандартные хоткеи что бы после написания команды в терминале быстро вернуться к редактированию открытого файла?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сочетание клавиш **Ctrl + ' (тильда).** Если вы редактируете код, нажатие этого хоткея развернет терминал и вы сможете вводить команды. Например node (тут имя вашего исходника). После того как отладили или проверили код, еще раз нажимаем ctrl + ' и фокус переключается на код (нижняя панель с терминалом скрывается).